# ostream error. Can anybody debug this?

Tags: c++, filestream, iostream

I want the following values to be written into the file using ostream???

```
int main ()
{
  FILE * pFile;
  pFile = fopen ("myfile.txt","w");
  if (pFile!=NULL)
  {
    fputs ("fopen example",pFile);
    fclose (pFile);
  }
  pFile<< "r "<<" " <<"ggjjsss" <<'_'<<"gggjj"<< " " << "HLLO " <<endl;
}
```

I am getting the following error..
error: invalid operands of types 'FILE*' and 'const char [3]' to binary 'operator<<'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are dealing with `FILE`, I would say it's an `ofstream` error rather than `ostream` error. :) `FILE` is a C-style file i/o for which `operator <<` is not overloaded.

You should use `ofstream` object for which the `operator <<` is overloaded in the library.

```
#include<fstream>

ofstream File("myfile.txt");
File<< "r "<<" " <<"ggjjsss" <<'_'<<"gggjj"<< " " << "HLLO " <<endl;
```

Comment: I am getting the following error, what does this mean?? or: variable 'std::ofstream File' has initializer but incomplete type

Comment: #include <fstream> should help.

Comment: @Invictus, have you `#include<fstream>` at the top ?

Answer (score 2):

FILE * is not a ostream in the sense of C++'s standard library. Use fstream instead (or ofstream). Look here for an example: [cplusplus.com's fstream reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/fstream/)

Comment: Is there any way I can use ostream to write into a file??

Comment: @Invictus, `<fstream>` library already provides `ofstream` (and `fstream`, `ifstream`); which are meant for C++ file handling.

Answer (score 1):

You are confused. In classic C sense "stream" is just something you can read from/write to. In c++ "streams" are specials objects, that comply with very specific interface.

Stream operator << is available only in C++, therefore it would very logical not to expect it to work on classic C libraries